# Alternative to public-facing website

Tags: sharepoint-online, public-website

We currently use a public-facing website (set up years ago) to allow members at my workplace the ability to login with their Microsoft accounts, upload their documents, and make blog posts for the public to view.

Since public-facing websites have been discontinued and will be expiring, is there any alternative service that will provide a similar kind of functionality? We provide members with Microsoft accounts so keeping a system as similar to what we currently have is fairly important.

Answer (score 1):

Regular SharePoint Site will allow public to see posts if appropriate "Anonymous Access" has been configured. See reference [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-anonymous-access-3647cdd5-1ab8-48cf-b4ee-d1b652bbabdd) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Many hosting providers offer SharePoint environments; so you would be running your 'own' server. Be prepared to pay though, those licenses are not cheap.

Or you could go all the way and run SharePoint on your own public infrastructure, you then have to maintain firewalls, load balancing servers and the lot yourself.

Search for "Hybrid SharePoint"

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint doesn't allow you to create Public facing sites anymore. You should explore PowerApps Portal where you can give internal and external users secure access to your data either anonymously or through commercial authentication providers like LinkedIn, Microsoft, Facebook, and Google, or enterprise providers such as Azure AD B2C and Okta

Answer (score -1):

We use sharepoint for that, check office 365 plans for more detail. you can login with Microsoft account and use company accounts. available on mobile and give better experience.

Comment: Will a regular SharePoint site still allow the public to see blog posts that we submit?

Comment: ah, ok, my bad, I thought you are asking for non public intranet solution only but sharepoint does offer a public facing website as well, we never used but I see a public site sitting there.